# Error publish a lwc in Experience cloud "window.$ is not a function"

Tags: lightning-web-components, carousel, experience, crm

I have created a LWC in which I load the jQuery library as a static resource. When I publish the component in the experience cloud I get the error "window.$ is not a function". This same component deploying it in CRM works correctly.

This is the code in js:

```
renderedCarrousel() {
    
    loadStyle(this, owlCarousel+'/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css')
    loadStyle(this, owlCarousel+'/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css')
    loadScript(this, jQuery)
        .then(e => {
            loadScript(this, owlCarousel+'/OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/owl.carousel.min.js')
            .then(() => {
                console.log("I render");
                const carousel = this.template.querySelector('div[class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded"]');
                window.$(carousel).owlCarousel({
                    //window.jQuery(carousel).owlCarousel({
                        
                    items: 3,
                    margin: 10,
                    stagePadding: 30,
                    responsive: {
                        0:{
                            items:1
                        }
                    }
                })

            })
    })
   
}
```